# Which intensity functions are allowed in a non homogeneous Poisson process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-process

Supose $(X_t)$ is a non homogeneous Poisson process with intensity function $r$. Let $T_1$ be the first arrival time of the process and $R(t) = \int_0^t r$. Then

\begin{align*}
{\bf{P}}(T_1>t) &= {\bf P}(X_t < 1)\\
&= {\bf P}(X_t = 0)\\
&= \exp(-R(t))
\end{align*}

Thus

$$R(t)=-\log({\bf P}(T_1>t))$$
and
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} R(t) = \infty$$

However, for homework my professor defined $r(t) := \exp(-t)$ for which $R(t) = 1 - \exp(-t)$. We also saw some examples for which $r$ has finite support.

I guess for applications we could define $r$ as 1 after the interval of time in which we are interested, but it seems too artificial for theoretical purposes. Is this necessary? Which other properties should $r$ satisfy?

I was asked to calculate the distribution and expectation of $T_1$ for $r(t) := \exp(-t)$ . What should I write? It seems dangerous to "do probability" and use theorems with a distribution function that isn't actually a distribution, but maybe it's not too wrong?

I saw on some websites that measure theory is used for this. I know only the basics of Lebesgue measure and integration.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When $r$ and therefore $R$ are not random you can obviously choose any $r$ s.t. $\mathbb P(T_1>t)=e^{-R(t)}$ is a probability in $[0,1]\,.$ In terms of $r$ this means nonnegative. That's the only necessary condition. I don't really get what you are asking here. What is dangerous/wrong ?

Comment: When $r(t) = e^{-t}$, ${\bf P} (T_1 > t) = e^{e^{-t} -1}$. But then $\lim_{t\to\infty} {\bf P} (T_1 \leq t) = 1 - \lim_{t\to\infty} {\bf P} (T_1 > t) = 1 - e^{-1}$. I was told this can't happen because the distribution function of a r.v. should converge to 1 at infinity. @KurtG.

Comment: My professor (at last) answered my emails and told me that my calculations are correct, but it's not a contradiction since it's possible for a r.v. to be infinite with positive probability.

Comment: This is all correct.